# Произвольный тип записей

Tags: wordpress

На сайте есть страница, где выводятся термины. термины подразделяются на рубрики и эти рубрики с терминами выводятся в столбцы.

Я создал кастомный тип записей "Термины" и создал рубрику для них "Тип термина". Когда вывожу записи на страницу. То термины не привязываются к отмеченной рубрике, а отображаются сразу во всех рубриках.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Кастомный тип ТЕРМИНЫ

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_terms() {
    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( 'Термины', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "singular_name" => __( 'Термин', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "menu_name" => __( 'Термины', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "all_items" => __( 'Все термины', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "add_new" => __( 'Добавить термин', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "add_new_item" => __( 'Добавить новый термин', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "edit_item" => __( 'Редактировать термин', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "new_item" => __( 'Новый термин', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "view_item" => __( 'Просмотреть термин', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "view_items" => __( 'Просмотреть термины', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "search_items" => __( 'Поиск терминов', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "not_found" => __( 'Термины не найдены', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "not_found_in_trash" => __( 'Термины не найдены в корзине', 'twentytwelve' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        "label" => __( 'Термины', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "Термины",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "menu_icon" => "dashicons-list-view",
        "has_archive" => 'terms',
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "terms", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "custom-fields", "revisions" ),
    );
    register_post_type( "terms", $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_terms' );`



    //Новая таксономия ТЕРМИНЫ
function cptui_register_my_taxes_terms_types() {
    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( 'Тип терминов', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "singular_name" => __( 'Тип термина', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "all_items" => __( 'Все типы терминов', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "edit_item" => __( 'Редактировать тип термина', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "add_new_item" => __( 'Добавить новый тип термина', 'twentytwelve' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        "label" => __( 'Тип термина', 'twentytwelve' ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "public" => false,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "label" => "Тип термина",
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "query_var" => true,
        "rewrite" => false,
        "show_admin_column" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "show_in_quick_edit" => false,
    );
    register_taxonomy( "terms-types", array( "terms" ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_terms_types' );





<div class="content">

  <div class="terms-row">

                <?php
                $terms_type = get_terms(array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'terms-types',
                    'hide_empty' => 0,

                ));
                ?>
                <?php if ( $terms_type ) { ?>

                <?php foreach ( $terms_type as $type ) { ?>

                <div class="terms-col">
                    <h3><?php echo $type->name; ?></h3>
                        <?php $terms = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'terms')); ?>
                        <?php if ($terms->have_posts()) : while ($terms->have_posts()) : $terms->the_post(); ?>

                        <div class="terms-item">
                        <h4 class="terms-item-title"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></h4>
                        <div class="terms-content">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <?php endwhile;
                        else: echo '<h2>Извините, ничего не найдено...</h2>'; endif; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </div>

                <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>

  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что собственно не так, если у вас логика сломана ? Есть пост тип `terms` и таксономия к нему `term_types` . Вы в кастомном цикле на страницу выводите все термы, и далле все посты типа  `terms` и не важно, ли они относятся к даному терму, или вообще к таксономии `term_types`.

Comment: @NikPashchuk. Так как быть тогда? Уже голова не варит. Может быть решение и простое, но додуматься я до него не могу

Comment: У вас есть все, что нужно, только ошибка в логике.
1. Поприкреплять к постам нужные категории и термины
2. Изменить параметры выборки постов в цикле, а именно не `'post_type' => 'terms' `, а хотябы `'post_type' => 'terms', 'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'terms-types',
            'field'     => 'term_id',
            'terms'     => array( $type->term_id )
        )
    )`

Answer (score 0):

Как я описал проблему в коментариях, но повторюсь снова, и напишу правильный вывод постов согласно вашего кода регистрации кастомного типа записи и таксономий к нему, итак:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="terms-row">
        <?php $terms_type = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy'   => 'terms-types',
                                              'hide_empty' => 0
        ) ); // Ну тут всё понятно, достаним все категориии таксономии "Тип терминов"
        if ( $terms_type ) { // Если есть хотябы одна категория, продолжаем
            foreach ( $terms_type as $type ) { ?>
                <div class="terms-col">
                    <h3><?php echo $type->name; // Название категории из "Тип терминов"?></h3>
                    <?php
                    // Получим посты посты не только по параметру 'post_type' => 'terms', а те, которые также относятся к даной категории $type
                    $load  = [
                        'post_type'   => 'terms',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'tax_query'   => [
                            [
                                'taxonomy' => 'terms-types',
                                'field'    => 'term_id',
                                'terms'    => [ $type->term_id ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ];
                    $terms = new WP_Query( $load );
                    if ( $terms->have_posts() ) : while ( $terms->have_posts() ) : $terms->the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="terms-item">
                            <h4 class="terms-item-title"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></h4>
                            <div class="terms-content">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile;
                    else: echo '<h2>Извините, ничего не найдено...</h2>'; endif; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </div>

            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Будет вывод сначало категорий "Тип терминов" и потом уже прикрепленные к ней посты типа `terms`. Категорию вбудет выводить, даже если к ней нету постов.